# How can I add a new field into Firestore with a random name?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a todo app, and I am trying to give every new todo a uniques ID, as such:

```
        const key = uuid();
        if( inp.length > 0 ) {
            db.collection("todos").doc(uid).set({
                key:{
                    title: inp,
                    desc: 'die',
                    name: key
                }
            }, {merge: true})
        }
```

( the uuid() is taken from an NPM package)

Of course, that doesn't work. I was wondering if there is any way I could do that?

Comment: Describe not working.

Comment: Your question should go into more detail about what it's working the way you expect.  I will point out that you're not checking for errors anywhere.  `set()` returns a promise that indicates if the operation succeeded or failed.